# How to fix write.csv to save the data in Cyrillic characters?

Tags: r, csv, save, readr

When I save the data by employing base `write.csv`, it transforms all the Russian characters into `<U+041F>`. The same exactly happens with `write_csv` of readr package within tidyverse. What can I do to preserve the same characters while saving?

```
<U+041F><U+0440><U+043E><U+0434><U+0430><U+0435><U+0442><U+0441><U+044F> 
<U+043A><U+0432><U+0430><U+0440><U+0442><U+0438><U+0440><U+0430>
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify encoding `fileEncoding = ""` inside `write.csv()` function?  So, for example `write.csv(df,"df.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Sounds like you are working on Windows.  You should try the R-devel UCRT build:  it is supposed to fix things like this.  Get it from CRAN, here:  https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Cyrillic characters from R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471819/export-cyrillic-characters-from-r)